# Multi match query with terms lookup searching multiple indices elasticsearch 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

All,
    I am working on  building a NEST 6.x query that takes a serach term and looks in different fields in different indices.
    This is the one I got so far but is not returning any results that I am expecting.

Please see the details below

**Indices used**

1. dev-sample-search
2. user-agents-search

The way the search should work is as follows.

1. The value in the query field(**27921093**) is searched against the
   fields **agentNumber, customerName, fileNumber, documentid**(These are all
              analyzed fileds).
2. The search should limit the documents to the **agentNumbers** the user
   **sampleuser@gmail.com** has access to( sample data for
              user-agents-search) is added below.
3. **agentNumber, customerName, fileNumber, documentid** and status are
   part of the index dev-sample-search.
4. **status**  field is defined as a **keyword**.
5. The fields in the **user-agents-search** index are all **keywords**

   **Sample user-agents-search index data:**

   ```
    {
                 "id": "sampleuser@gmail.com"",
                 "user": "sampleuser@gmail.com"",
                 "agentNumber": [
                   "123.456.789",
                   "1011.12.13.14"
                 ]
       }
   ```

**Sample dev-sample-search index data:**

```
{

          "agentNumber": "123.456.789",          
          "customerName": "Bank of america",
          "fileNumber":"test_file_1123",
          "documentid":"1234456789"
 }

GET dev-sample-search/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "best_fields",
            "query": "27921093",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "agentNumber",
              "customerName",
              "fileNumber",              
              "documentid^10"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "agentNumber": {
                    "index": "user-agents-search",
                    "type": "_doc",
                    "user": "sampleuser@gmail.com",
                    "path": "agentNumber"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "pending"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "cancelled"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "app cancelled"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "active"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "status": {
                          "value": "terminated"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things that you may want to look at:

1. In the `terms` lookup query, `"user": "sampleuser@gmail.com",` should be `"id": "sampleuser@gmail.com",`.
2. If at least one `should` clause in the `filter` clause should match, set  `"minimum_should_match" : 1` on the `bool` query containing the `should` clause

Comment: Thanks @Russ Cam. Another question I have is, while querying multiple indices, should we specify the index context for each filed and if we don't, does ES look for that field in all the indices?